# foreach inside foreach doubling result

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am using laravel and have a for each loop going through an api response,

this loops some html accoridan and php data which works fine.

next on the accoridan drop down i have a second loop which loops through a seperate array of ojbects to display the data i need.

should i combine arrays? brake a the first loop? 
not really sure whats next

here is my view

```
     @foreach(array_slice($nearbysearchresults->results, 0, 5) as $result)
             <div class="accordion" id="toggleArea">
                 <div class="accordion-group">
                    <div class="accordion-heading accordionize">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionArea" href="#{{$result->place_id}}Area">
                        {{$result->name}}
                        {{$result->vicinity}}
                        <td><span class="font-icon-ok-sign" style="padding-left: 10px;"></span></td> 
                        <td><span class="font-icon-ok-sign"  style="padding-left: 10px;"></span></td>
                        <td><span class="font-icon-ok-sign"  style="padding-left: 10px;"></span><span class="font-icon-ok-sign"  style="padding-left: 10px;"></span><span class="font-icon-ok-sign"  style="padding-left: 10px;"></span><span class="font-icon-ok-sign"  style="padding-left: 10px;"></span><span class="font-icon-ok-sign"  style="padding-left: 10px;"></span></td>  
                        <td><span class="font-icon-ok-sign"  style="padding-left: 10px;"></span><span class="font-icon-ok-sign"  style="padding-left: 10px;"></span><span class="font-icon-ok-sign"  style="padding-left: 10px;"></span><span class="font-icon-ok-sign"  style="padding-left: 10px;"></span><span class="font-icon-ok-sign"  style="padding-left: 10px;"></span></td>  
                        <td></td> 
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="{{$result->place_id}}Area" class="accordion-body collapse">
                        <div class="accordion-inner">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="span12">
                                        <div class="info-block">
                                           <div class="info-text">


                                               <p>test</p>

                                             @foreach($placesearchresults as $placesearchresult)
                                                 {{$placesearchresult->result->name}}
                                             @endforeach
                                                <a class="button" target="_blank" href="">Visit Site</a> 


                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>  
                                </div>       
                             </div>
                         </div>
                    </div>
              </div>


      @endforeach
```

Comment: Since your code works i think this is the better site for this question: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (Also the code looks fine for me, only that you use `@` which hides error so i would remove them and capsule the php code in tags like `<?php ... '>`)

Comment: ok thanks will do, i am basically getting   all 5 {{$placesearchresult->result->name}} in each of the accordian loops, when i run the code outside the other foreach it works fine and displays all 5 as it should